# Taylor polynomial of an integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

How do you write the $(n+1)$th Taylor polynomial of an integral at $x_0$?

I.e. how do you expand
$$T_{n+1, x_0} \left ( \int_{x_0}^xf(t)dt \right )$$

---

The reason it's $(n+1)$th is because the Taylor expansion for just $ƒ(t)$ would be of order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's really the Taylor expansion of the function $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) \; dt.$  By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F^{\prime}(x) = f(x)$.  So the Taylor series start out $F(x_0)+F^{\prime}(x_0)(x-x_0) + F^{\prime\prime}(x_0)(x-x_0)^2/2 +\cdots.$  But (clearly) $F(x_0)=0$ and each $F^{(n)}=f^{(n-1)}$,
so the series becomes $f(x_0)(x-x_0)+f^{\prime}(x_0)(x-x_0)^2/2 + \cdots.$

Alternatively, you could replace $f(t)$ by its Taylor series in the integrand and integrate term by term.  (Valid as long as the series is absolutely convergent.)

Comment: $F(x_0)=0$ because $F(x)=\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt = F(x)-F(x_0)$ $\implies$ $F(x_0) = 0$?

Comment: Yes.  Or just because you're integrating from $x_0$ to $x_0$.